# How .Net names its temp folder inside C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v{version}\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root

Tags: c#, .net, iis, msbuild, application-pool

I have some websites on my IIS machine. Lets say `WebsiteA`, `WebsiteB` and `WebsiteC`.

Inside `.Net` temp folder

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\{folderName}`

each of the 3 website will have their own folder with some random name.

For example:

- `WebsiteA` is using a folder named `5a3e1z1j`. This folder will have the following path :

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5a3e1z1j`

- `WebsiteB` is using a folder named `b51o8881`. This folder will have the following path :

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\b51o8881`

- `WebsiteC` is using a folder named `ad4966a9`. This folder will have the following path:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\ad4966a9`

How do I know which website is using which folder? So while the process of that website is still running, it won't allow me to delete the folder. It will only allow to delete the folder if I kill the process / stop the application pool or IIS.

Then I did some testing, what if I delete the folder (of course while there is no running process), what will happen to the site.

So apparently it will create a new folder with same exact random name.

Then I come up with a conclusion that this name is stored somewhere, so even though the folder is deleted. It will be recreated back with the same name.

My question is "How .Net create the name of these .Net temp folder so that for each website will have a consistent folder name? If it's stored somewhere after a successful build of the website, where can I find it?"

What I am trying to achieve is I want to create a tool that will do application pool restart if it's given input of website name. And also at the same time delete the .Net temp folder. But only the one associated to the input website.

If something is not clear, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: This question goes too deep into Microsoft's private implementation of ASP.NET. Thus, unless Microsoft provides the details, nobody can answer it.

Comment: answered by scott hansleman here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523915/how-to-determine-the-temporary-asp-net-files-root-site-hash-with-powershell